# Bootstrap-table calling dotnet core 3.1 Razor Pagemodel via Ajax

Tags: ajax, .net-core, razor-pages, bootstrap-table

```
$("#mTable").bootstrapTable({
    method: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Page("Listing", "Query")",
    pagination: true,
    sidePagination: "server",
    ajaxOptions: { headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() } },
    queryParams: function (params) {
        return {
            limit: params.limit,    //Page size
            offset: params.offset,  //Page number
            sort: params.sort,      //Sort column names
            order: params.order     //Ranking command( desc，asc)
        };
    }
    // .. The rest of the core are not important
```

My Razor Page handler

```
public JsonResult OnPostQuery(int limit, int offset, string sort, string order)
{
    return null;
}
```

The **bootstrap-table** is able to invoke **OnPostQuery()** handler, but all the parameters are either 0 or null.

Anyone know what had gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
```